# Android Release build has a bug not in debug

Tags: android, build, retrofit, release, moshi

I'm using retrofit and moshi to query a api and display some results in my app. Everything works fine when debugging but when I enable minifyEnabled and build a release aab(android app bundle) and upload it to the Google Play Store I encounter a bug.

My app queries the api and displays some results in a recyclerview, pretty simple. But when the bug is involved the recyclerview items are blank but there is the correct number of results. For example if the user searches for "Boston" it may get 15 results back but with the bug all the recyclerview items are empty.

Googling around suggests it's a proguard/r8 problem. I have added the following proguard/r8 rules provided by retrofit, moshi, okhttp but the bug still happens.

I cant' see anything interesting in logcat when running the release version and enabling minifyEnabled in debug does not produce the bug.

```
# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters. InnerClasses is required to use Signature and
# EnclosingMethod is required to use InnerClasses.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod

# Retrofit does reflection on method and parameter annotations.
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*

# With R8 full mode, it sees no subtypes of Retrofit interfaces since they are created with a Proxy
# and replaces all potential values with null. Explicitly keeping the interfaces prevents this.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>

# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}

-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

# Enum field names are used by the integrated EnumJsonAdapter.
# values() is synthesized by the Kotlin compiler and is used by EnumJsonAdapter indirectly
# Annotate enums with @JsonClass(generateAdapter = false) to use them with Moshi.
-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    **[] values();
}

# The name of @JsonClass types is used to look up the generated adapter.
-keepnames @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class *

# Retain generated target class's synthetic defaults constructor and keep DefaultConstructorMarker's
# name. We will look this up reflectively to invoke the type's constructor.
#
# We can't _just_ keep the defaults constructor because Proguard/R8's spec doesn't allow wildcard
# matching preceding parameters.
-keepnames class kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker
-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass @kotlin.Metadata class * {
    synthetic <init>(...);
}

# Retain generated JsonAdapters if annotated type is retained.
-if @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class *
-keep class <1>JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
-if @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class **$*
-keep class <1>_<2>JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
-if @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class **$*$*
-keep class <1>_<2>_<3>JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
-if @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class **$*$*$*
-keep class <1>_<2>_<3>_<4>JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
-if @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class **$*$*$*$*
-keep class <1>_<2>_<3>_<4>_<5>JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
-if @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class **$*$*$*$*$*
-keep class <1>_<2>_<3>_<4>_<5>_<6>JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}

-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

###########################################################################################
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson <methods>;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson <methods>;
}

-keepnames @kotlin.Metadata class us.roob.ebb.data.models.**
-keep class us.roob.ebb.data.models.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class us.roob.ebb.data.models.** { *; }

##
-keepnames @kotlin.Metadata class us.roob.ebb.data.remote.**
-keep class us.roob.ebb.data.remote.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class us.roob.ebb.data.remote.** { *; }
```

Comment: What moshi version do you use? It looks like your DTO (deserialised objects) are obfuscated. Are they java or kotlin classes?

Comment: I'm using  retrofit version = 2.6.1. All of this codebase is kotlin.

Comment: @rOOb85 Have you resolved this?